# How to get the property axioms using Jena?

Tags: jena, owl

Suppose, in one ontology, there is an object property named "isFriendOf", and this property is a transitive property.

```
<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/example#isFriendOf">
  <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#TransitiveProperty"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>
```

Now, I want to check what property axioms this property has. How to use Jena to get this information? Thanks!

Comment: "What property axioms this property has" -> you mean to check for functional, transitiv, etc.? Have you tried to look into the documentation: https://jena.apache.org/documentation/ontology/  and maybe tried to use the Javadoc: https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/ ?

Comment: Then, next question. Why Jena and not OWL API? Note, the Jena Ontology API covers only OWL 1, thus, some property characteristics are not covered by the API. An alternative solution would be to use a SPARQL query like `SELECT ?o WHERE {<http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/example#isFriendOf> a ?o}`

Answer (score 0):

Jena does not support axiomatic view of ontology.
Actually it does not support OWL2 at all.

So you can't receive list of axioms using only jena, just because there are no such objects inside OntModel jena subsystem (see package org.apache.jena.ontology).

But you can use OWL-API. 
Try to list all related axioms (see method org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLAxiomCollection#referencingAxioms from OWL-API), it would be something like this:

`OWLOntology ont = ...;
ont.referencingAxioms(IRI.create("http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/example#isFriendOf")).forEach(System.out::println);`

There is another option.

Since we are faced with the same problem of jena/owl2 compatibility too, we are released our own solution in order to to reconcile these two semantic web technology.
It is called [ONT-API](https://github.com/avicomp/ont-api), (sorry for adverts).
In this case you can use the same method but having consistent org.apache.jena.rdf.model.Model (org.apache.jena.graph.Graph) object at the same time.

Hope it will help

Comment: Thank you! I'll check both api.